# Wait for AddIn uninstallation

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, csom

I'm in the process of writing some **PowerShell** script to do some work with SharePoint Online AddIns (`.app`), have a look at the image below:

[image]

As you can see from the highlighted syntax, I'm telling the session to have a 10 sec nap after the removal of the AddIn to make sure that next statement doesn't crash saying that the AddIn instance already exists, and it works fine, but sometimes these processes could hang for many minutes, or even hours, therefore, 
I want the session to know when the current job is done without me specifying 10 seconds.

I have searched and tried using below,

```
Start-Job -Name "MyJob" -ScriptBlock { Do some work that could take time }

function WaitForJobToFinish([string]$currentJob)
{ 
    $JobName = $currentJob
    $job = Get-Job | ?{ $_.Name -like $JobName }
    if ($job -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host 'Timer job not found'
    }
    else
    {
        $JobFullName = $job.Name
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "Waiting to finish job $JobFullName"
        while ((Get-Job $JobFullName) -ne $null) 
        {
            Write-Host -NoNewLine .
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        }
        Write-Host  "Finished waiting for job.."
    }
}

WaitForJobToFinish MyJob
```

No matter what I put inside the `-ScriptBlock` the session gets stuck:

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve that?